# Error using teubner package (XeLaTeX)

Tags: fonts, xetex, errors

I'm using the `teubner` package to typeset ancient greek characters. However, I think that it conflicts with another package, because when I use it, this message appears:

```
LaTeX Error: Command `\breve' already defined.
```

If I remove `\usepackage{teubner}`, the error disappears.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}                           
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                        
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}                    
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}       
\usepackage{teubner}                       % If I remove this line, the error disappears

\begin{document}

Θουκυδίδης Ἀθηναῖος ξυνέγραψε τὸν πόλεμον τῶν Πελοποννησίων καὶ Ἀθηναίων, ὡς ἐπολέμησαν πρὸς ἀλλήλους, ἀρξάμενος εὐθὺς καθισταμένου καὶ ἐλπίσας μέγαν τε ἔσεσθαι καὶ ἀξιολογώτατον τῶν προγεγενημένων, τεκμαιρόμενος ὅτι ἀκμάζοντές τε ᾖσαν ἐς αὐτὸν ἀμφότεροι παρασκευῇ τῇ πάσῃ καὶ τὸ ἄλλο Ἑλληνικὸν ὁρῶν ξυνιστάμενον πρὸς ἑκατέρους, τὸ μὲν εὐθύς, τὸ δὲ καὶ διανοούμενον.

\end{document}
```

Comment: the package is not meant to be used with xetex, that is a pdftex package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is there any way to make it available in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: sorry, I neither know greek nor what the package is actually trying to achieve.